# Using .append() + css/styling to add new text using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add new html to a selector that I have, so I think I need to use .append(). At the same time I also want to make the new strings become different colors, fonts etc.

I want the last .css to make just the new, appended html become pink (or whatever) and *not* the test string. Any pointers would be great.

Below doesn't work because of the last .css.  How do I fix this?  Thanks!

```
  test_string = "hi there,";
  $('#testie').html(test_string).css("font-size", "40px").append(" pink string").css('color', 'pink');
```

(note: new to Javascript/Jquery in general so any help/suggestions is appreciated)

Comment: You can't add style to text, you need to create a new element, either a DIV or a SPAN, and put the style there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `span` for the new strings

```js
 test_string = "hi there,";

 $('body').html(test_string).css("font-size", "40px");

var newtext = $('<span />').css('color', 'pink');
     newtext.html(" pink string");

$('body').html(test_string).css("font-size", "40px").append(newtext);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```